# Problem to include flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I am trying to include a flow chart as figure in my document but I think I am doing something wrong. After compile I get blank page in my PDF document. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and Windows 7. Here is part of the LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]\label{flowchart:algorithmchart}
 Place nodes with matrix nodes
 \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{%
    \node [block] (init) {Set Quotient to 0};\\
    \node [block] (identify) {Subtract Divisor from Dividend};\\
    \node [block] (evaluate) {Add 1 to Quotient};\\
    \node [decision] (decide) {is Result Register Greater than 0?};\\
    \node [block] (stop) {Stop - Quotient is Correct};\\};
 Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node[right]{No} (stop);
    \path [line] (stop) -- ++(2,0) |- (identify);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: indenting code by 4 spaces renders it properly. The easiest way is to highlight the code and click the '{}' button in the toolbar.

Comment: It compiles fine here. Did you check that the code you posted demonstrates the problem? If so, try deleting any generated files (`*.aux` etc.) and recompiling.

Comment: Yes, I did the same but still the problem is same. It create nothing, only blank page is there.

Comment: It also compiles just fine here.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the output when you compile? The code is right as far as I can tell (and Svend Tveskæg confirms) so the problem must lie elsewhere. Maybe some clue in the log?

Comment: In log file it shows [Missing character: There is no P in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!]

Comment: Ohh. I found out my error. It does not work in dvi~pdf but work in dvi~ps~pdf. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by switching to an appropriate toolchain for TikZ.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by switching to an appropriate toolchain for TikZ.